# Why does this static_assert only fail with clang on OS X and nowhere else?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

The following code:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

enum class Enum : std::uint64_t {
    zero,
};

static_assert(std::is_same<std::make_unsigned<Enum>::type, std::uint64_t>::value, "");
```

fails to compile on OS X with clang:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 -c t.cpp
t.cpp:8:1: error: static_assert failed ""
static_assert(std::is_same<std::make_unsigned<Enum>::type, std::uint64_t>::value, "");
^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated
```

However, this same file works okay with clang 3.8/3.7.1/3.7/3.6/3.5.1/3.5/3.4.1/3.3 on [gcc.godbolt.org](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:clang380,options:'-c+-std%3Dc%2B%2B11',source:'%23include+%3Ccstdint%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Aenum+class+Enum+:+std::uint64_t+%7B%0A++++zero,%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astatic_assert(std::is_same%3Cstd::make_unsigned%3CEnum%3E::type,+std::uint64_t%3E::value,+%22%22)%3B%0A')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3).

On my system, clang is just the normal version from Xcode 7.3.1:

```
$ clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

What gives? This clearly seems to be a bug in clang on my system, but it's not clear to me why this would fail with clang from Xcode but not any of the other versions of clang. Is Xcode's clang distribution significantly different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a bug; the behavior is mandated by the standard. [[meta.trans.sign]](http://eel.is/c++draft/meta.trans.sign) says for the enumeration case

> `type` shall name the unsigned integer type with smallest
>   rank ([conv.rank]) for which `sizeof(T) == sizeof(type)`, with the
>   same cv-qualifiers as `T`.

In platforms where `sizeof(unsigned long long) == sizeof (unsigned long)`, `std::uint64_t` may be defined as either, but `std::make_unsigned<Enum>::type` must name `unsigned long`.